Force Android to use mobile data even if other network sources are available?
I have an Android device that's used for mobile testing. This device has cell connectivity and is separately connected to an ethernet cable (used for ADB).
How can I configure the Android device so that mobile data is used for internet connectivity and NOT the ethernet connection?
adb shell ifconfig lists the active network interfaces:
eth0      Link encap:UNSPEC    Driver r8152
          inet addr:192.168.1.194  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0 
          inet6 addr: fe80::acc9:34c6:24a1:f137/64 Scope: Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2141 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0 
          TX packets:792 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:559025 TX bytes:84086 

rmnet_data0 Link encap:UNSPEC  
          inet addr:10.76.204.250  Mask:255.255.255.252 
          inet6 addr: 2600:380:c034:e7ed:b901:d247:67b4:d598/64 Scope: Global
          UP RUNNING  MTU:1430  Metric:1
          RX packets:8811 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0 
          TX packets:6886 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:7386188 TX bytes:1569087 

...

Looking to set rmnet_data0 (mobile data) to be the network interface used for internet instead of eth0. Device can be rooted if needed.

Cross posted on Stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/q/78767637/150978
